# ion-toggle como disparar evento quando marcar

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript

Tenho seguinte código:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let dispositivo of dispositivos">
<ion-label>{{dispositivo.Nome}}</ion-label>
<ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-positive" [(ngModel)]="dispositivo.Status" data-ng-change="acao(dispositivo)"></ion-toggle>
```

quero disparar

```
acao(dispositivo: any) {

  //algo aqui
```

}

Neste código ele não chega no evento acao.

Answer (score 0):

Midana,

Use o event binding do ion-toggle que é o ionChange ou seja.

```
<ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-positive" [(ngModel)]="dispositivo.Status" [ionChange]="acao(dispositivo)"></ion-toggle>
```

Conforme documentação do ionic2:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toggle/Toggle/

Lembrando que provavelmente você deverá verificar qual o valor atual do toggle.